# How to use static column in scylladb and cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I am new in scylladb and cassandra, I am facing some issues in querying data from the table, following is the schema I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE usercontacts (
  userID bigint,                        -- userID 
  contactID bigint,                     -- Contact ID lynkApp userID  
  contactDeviceToken text,              -- Device Token    
  modifyDate timestamp static ,     
  PRIMARY KEY  (contactID,userID)
);



CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW usercontacts_by_contactid 
AS SELECT userID, contactID, contactDeviceToken,
FROM usercontacts 
contactID IS NOT NULL AND userID IS NOT NULL AND modifyDate IS NOT NULL 
-- Need to not null as these are the primary keys in main
-- table same structure as the main table
PRIMARY KEY(userID,contactID);



CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW usercontacts_by_modifyDate 
AS SELECT userID,contactID,contactDeviceToken,modifyDate
FROM usercontacts WHERE
contactID IS NOT NULL AND userID IS NOT NULL AND modifyDate IS NOT NULL
-- Need to not null as these are the primary keys in main
-- table same structure as the main table
PRIMARY KEY (modifyDate,contactID);
```

I want to  create materialized view for contact table which is `usercontacts_by_userid` and `usercontacts_by_modifydate`

I need the following queries in case of when I set modifydate (timestamp) static:

```
update usercontacts set modifydate="newdate" where contactid="contactid"
select * from usercontacts_by_modifydate where modifydate="modifydate"
delete from usercontacts where contactid="contactid"
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not currently possible to create a materialized view that includes a static column, either as part of the primary key or just as a regular column.

Including a static row would require the whole base table (`usercontacts`) to be read when the static column is changed, so that the view rows could be re-calculated. This has a significant performance penalty.

Having the static row be the view's partition key means that there would only be one entry in the view for all the rows of a partition. However, secondary indexes do work in this case, and you can use that instead.

This is valid for both Scylla and Cassandra at the moment.